# Java hashmap iterate only certain keys

Tags: java, hashmap, yaml

I'm looking for a way to get the values for just a specific key when I get into the second loop here.  I'm using snakeyaml and loading it to a Map.  My yaml looks something like this:

```
number:
  id: status.number
  label: Number
contactType:
  id: status.contact_type
  label: Contact Type
```

What I'm attempting to do is just get the key and value for id.  It's probably super obvious, but I haven't found a way to do so.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> a = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) yaml.load(input);

for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> t : a.entrySet()) {
    String key = t.getKey();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : t.getValue().entrySet()) {
       System.out.println("OuterKey: " + key + " InnerKey: " + e.getKey() + " VALUE:" + e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of your inner loop: `t.getValue().get("id")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value(s) for the "inner key", you don't need to loop through every inner map.

In the following example, I assume you already have an `innerKey` variable that holds the desired inner key.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> a = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) yaml.load(input);

for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> t : a.entrySet()) {
    String outerKey = t.getKey();
    String innerValue = t.getValue().get(innerKey);
    System.out.println("OuterKey: " + outerKey + " InnerKey: " + innerKey + " VALUE:" + innerValue);
}
```

Comment: Yup.  Staring me in the face.  Thank you very much!